# pass url information in segue

Tags: xcode, ios5, segue

I have 2 button set each with a segue to a view controller with a web view.  I'm try to load a url in the web view based on which button started the segue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"toWeb"]){
     NSString *abc = @"http://www.abc.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kmb];
    NetView *netview =[segue destinationViewController];
    [netview.internet loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];


}else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"toFacebook"]){
    NSString *fb = @"http://www.facebook.com/ABC?ref=hl";        
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:fb];
    NetView *netview =[segue destinationViewController];
    [netview.internet loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2]];
    }
     }
```

This is not working but I'm not getting any error just a bland view on the new screen. I'm not sure what the problem is.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the webview on the destination controller has not been loaded at this point. Just set a property on the destination controller to hold your url and then on its `viewDidLoad` method send the message to the webview in order to load the request. Something like this:

**NetView.h**

```
...
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *url;
```

**NetView.m**

```
...
@synthesize url;
```

**Your code snippet:**

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"toWeb"]){
    NetView *netview = [segue destinationViewController];
    netview.url = @"http://www.abc.com/";
}
...
```

**NetView.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
    [self.internet loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works fine now.  And thank you for answering so quickly, I really appreciate it.